# PHTML template not loading on localhost, does on live server

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a strange issue with a .phtml file that is loaded through a static block onto the homepage (Magento 1.8). Today I made a copy of the live shop to my localhost. Everything is set up as it should be and the shop is running smoothly, except for one particular part of it.

On the homepage, and subsequently, on every category page I have developed a category grid that automatically loads all categories that are a child of the active category. On the live site this is working as it should be. However, running the shop locally gives some problems when rendering the grid. In fact, it is not rendered at all. If I substitute the code with some simple HTML of even PHP all is well and the homepage is build up correctly. I've also tried deleting parts of the code to see where it fails but it seems that there are several instances of code that breaks the page.

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of behavior? A .phtml template that does render on a live server but breaks on localhost environment? Other static blocks that load .phtml template files into the shop are working just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that you downloaded all files and have the block directive in the homepage (exported the DB)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's a 1-on-1 copy of the live site including the DB

Comment: Did you check system.log or exception.log? Former would add a log if the block is not found. Latter if there is an exception.

Comment: Also does your dev and production environment differ in case-sensitive/insensitive filesystems. Best to check if the cases are correct.

Comment: Plez consider adding your custom code here, which you used to render child category of active category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok wow, found the problem. Enabled system log but did not found any problems. I forgot to turn on display_errors in my php.ini file (must have been late). After turning it on I got a PHP parse error that was pointing out a line stating an "endif" statement. No further explanation just a parse error (so no unexpected T_ENDIF or some kind). Removing the line would skip to the next endif. After inspecting the entire if statement I found out that for some reason I used the PHP shortcake to open the statement (

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!